# Creating custom graphics with Windows Phone XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-phone

I am creating a WP 8.1 app with MVVM Light Toolkit. I have to call a service of weather measurings information, and then, I have to create different graphics with the indicator showing the value of the service response. For example, I have this image:

[image: Empty Graphic]

And it should be like this:

[image: Complete graphic]

Or these images:

[image]

[image]

And should end up like this:

[image]

How can I get the position where I would put the shape indicating the value? Or in the second case, the needle pointing the value? And, how would I support multiple resolutions?

Comment: I was asking because I am new to Windows Phone development, and none of the people I know have done something like this before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should draw everything in a `Canvas` panel. There you can control the assets positions and transformations. This also requires to have objects to preserve the state of each thing. This question maybe doesn't have an easy answer but I strongly recommend to you learn about that in this links

- [Using XAML to write Windows 8 Games - Part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnkenn/archive/2013/07/10/using-xaml-to-write-windows-8-games.aspx)
- [Using XAML to
  write Windows 8 Games - Part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnkenn/archive/2013/07/10/using-xaml-to-write-windows-8-games-part-2.aspx)
- [Using XAML to write Windows 8
  Games - Part 3](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnkenn/archive/2013/07/10/using-xaml-to-write-windows-8-games-part-3.aspx)

Comment: I was thinking to use Canvas. I did not understand the part of having objects to preserve the state of each thing. This will be binded in One Way.

Comment: If you're trying yo make animations of any kind, you need to preserve the state for those animations. For example the Compass's needle needs to be draw in an specific rotation depending on the compass information. You need to have a value representing the angle (current rotation) to apply that transformation before the needle be redrow on the Canvas.